# Need help to find step response of RL circuits

Tags: inductor, step-response

Here is the question I am trying to solve:
[image: my question]

I drew my solution with calculations on paper. Before the key is closed, I calculated İ0 and then after the key is closed, I calculated the last current (I∞) on Inductor. I am not sure way of my solution is correct. Can someone look at if the way is true?
Here is my attempt:
[image: attempt]

I tried the solve the question by applying the steps in the example below.
[image: example]

Comment: Can you resolve the left side (switch open) as its Thevenin equivalent and replace it? Same with right side? All you have is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Judzu.png).

Comment: From that image, you should need almost no time at all to work out the initial condition for the current in the inductor. Once the switch is closed, you can compute the ***new*** Thevenin equivalent formed by the two earlier Thevenin voltage sources and their respective Thevenin source impedances. This will be a new voltage and a new impedance applied to the inductor.

Comment: On the left side, you computed 1 mA. This is the correct magnitude. But it is the wrong sign. Note that you have a -40 V supply over there (with respect to the bottom node being chosen as ground.)

Comment: I added one more question. While I am examing your answers can you look at it? please. This is the last question

Comment: You said "Once the switch is closed, you can compute the new Thevenin equivalent formed by the two earlier Thevenin voltage sources and their respective Thevenin source impedances. This will be a new voltage and a new impedance applied to the inductor." How can I do that exactly? Can you show me?

Comment: I've added some notes.

Answer (score 0):

Before switch closure, you have the following circuit (I chose your bottom node as ground):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHotnk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To find that, just notice that on the left side of your schematic you have a \$+200\:\text{V}\$ source applied to a divider pair of \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistors. This is a Thevenin voltage of \$+100\:\text{V}\$ and source impedance of \$5\:\text{k}\Omega\$. That's in series with \$20\:\text{k}\Omega\$ leading to the open switch. So the result is a Thevenin voltage of \$+100\:\text{V}\$ and source impedance of \$25\:\text{k}\Omega\$ on the left.

A similar process can be applied to the right side to find what I show above. You should have little difficulty agreeing with what I show there. (Though looking at your writing, I'm not so sure. So please see if you can find my result.)

Just before \$t=0\$, the inductor current will have been limited by the right-side \$20\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor to \$-1\:\text{mA}\$. Note the difference in sign with respect to what you show.

Once the switch is closed, find:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEguZd.png)</sup>

Note that in the earlier schematic there were two voltage sources and, again, a resistor divider between them. To find the Thevenin equivalent, you can just remove the inductor for a moment and apply KCL to the middle node. If you do that, you should find \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{V_{_{\text{TH}_1}}\cdot R_{_{\text{TH}_2}} + V_{_{\text{TH}_2}}\cdot R_{_{\text{TH}_1}}}{R_{_{\text{TH}_1}}+R_{_{\text{TH}_2}}}=+\frac{100}3\:\text{V}=+33.\overline{3}\:\text{V}\$. And the Thevenin resistance would be \$20\:\text{k}\Omega\,\mid\mid\,25\:\text{k}\Omega=\frac{100}9\:\text{k}\Omega=11.\overline{1}\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

You know the initial direction of \$I_{_\text{L}}\$ is opposite the arrow indication above, so the more positive end of the new Thevenin impedance will be the end connected to the inductor. You should be able to compute that initial voltage. And the differential equation again applies as with earlier questions you had. Similar flow to get all necessary results.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough to understand all of your notes about Thevenin. So I am confused right now. I understood what my wrong is about the İL (0). The sign was wrong and I got it after your explanation. But for another one, I mean, for İL(∞), I tried to use simplier way to find İL(∞). But I don't understand if my way is completely wrong. So I just want to ask you what are the results. I mean İL(∞) and İL(t) and R in İ(t). I wonder what are the numerical results of these 3 things.

Comment: @Computengineering It seems as though you may be still struggling a bit with the basics. This will make analysis a lot tougher because the calculus part is kind of the "next step up" that builds on earlier foundations. If you aren't fluent with Thevenin equivalents using just resistors and voltage sources, then you are going to be in a WORLD OF HURT when analyzing circuits that involve differential equations. So it sounds like you may want to spend some 'remedial time' on Thevenin with just voltage sources and resistors. Or do you feel solid about it and I'm getting you wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your warning but I won't specialize in circuit analysis. I mean I am a computer engineering student and my lessons are not that serious. It can be achieved by learning some basics not in depth. So my curriculum doesn't contain all you explained to me but it helped me a lot. Thank you